# Syncing without deleting

Tags: iphone

I got mt iPhone last september, and I never synced it to a computer. If i do so now will it erase everything on my iPhone or can i just do it?
My sister says you can just as long as I havent synced it to a computer.
Im connected to iCloud if that helps and I have backed up my storage.

Comment: What computer and iTunes are you syncing?

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely sync your iPhone to your computer, without having to worry about the data that is currently on your phone. In fact, [backing up and restoring](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1766) all the data currently on your device is done by syncing with iTunes (or iCloud).